# Simple way to programatically remove all grouping and filtering

Tags: ag-grid, asp.net-core-3.1

When the grid loads there is no grouping/filtering applied. I want to be able to remove any grouping/filtering which the user has applied manually i.e. get the grid format back to its original state.

Comment: if you are not bothered with what user's changes are in grid(lets say user added some data or edited some of it) then you can destroy and recreate the grid with default option like you do for the first time. else you can clear filters/pivot/grouping using api methods.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. No I can't do anything that will affect data (it's a logging implementation so data is flowing in all the time). Can you tell me exactly how I can clear filters/pivot/grouping using api methods? Some code samples would be really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function to reset everything

```
 function ResetGrid(){
   //clear filters
 gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
 //notify grid to implement the changes
 gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();

 //remove all pivots
 gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotColumns([]);
// disable pivot mode
 gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(false);
 //reset all grouping
 gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
//where columDefs is the object you used while creating grid first time.
  }
```

the above method does what you want but more sophisticated way to do this will be saving column state(it may be at iniital stage or later after certain operation).

```
    function saveState() {
     window.colState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
     window.groupState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnGroupState();
     window.sortState = gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
     window.filterState = gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();
     console.log('column state saved');
      }

    function restoreState() {
      if (!window.colState) {
        console.log('no columns state to restore by, you must save state first');
        return;
      }
      gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(window.colState);
      gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnGroupState(window.groupState);
      gridOptions.api.setSortModel(window.sortState);
      gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(window.filterState);
      console.log('column state restored');
    }

    function resetState() {
      gridOptions.columnApi.resetColumnState();
      gridOptions.columnApi.resetColumnGroupState();
      gridOptions.api.setSortModel(null);
      gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
      console.log('column state reset');
    }
```

here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5qXRvjHMpIzJYBhv)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can remove all filters and row groups. For more info, see [`GridApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/).

```js
gridApi.setFilterModel(null);
gridApi.setRowGroupColumns([]);
gridApi.onFilterChanged();
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit AgGrid - Remove Filter And Group]

Comment: Seems now this is a Grid Column API.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with help of **`gridOptions`** of **ag-grid**. Try to do the below changes..

Initialize `gridOptions` if not yet along with column definitions and set the grid options in `ag-grid`.

> **Component.ts**

```
this.gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true
  },
  columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
  rowData: this.rowData
};
```

clear the filters with like below

```
 ...
 gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
 gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
 ...
```

> **component.html**

```
<ag-grid ..  [gridOptions] = "gridOptions" ..> </ag-grid>
```

You can see more about this in the [**`ag-grid documentation`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/).